# where are the opengl libraries get stored on ubuntu : i need this to mention in my make file

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, ubuntu

where are the opengl libraries get stored on ubuntu9.10 : i need this to mention in my make file and what are all the link files i need to mention

Answer (score 12):

Install these to get OpenGL working:

**sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev**

**sudo apt-get install freeglut3**

**sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev**

The OpenGL files should be in:

**/usr/include/GL/**

The Terminal (Compiler) reads (e.g. g++) from:

**/usr/bin/**

Compile like this (you might need to link more libraries, but test this):

**g++** *filename* **-lglut -lGL -lGLU**

Answer (score 2):

/usr/lib/libGL.so

link with -lGL

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to mention their location explicitly in your `Makefile` since they should be in the standard library search path (probably in `/usr/lib`).

Like sisis wrote you should just need to add `-lGL` to the linker flags to link against `libGL.so` which might actually come from different sources: `mesa` or some fancy graphics card driver.

Answer (score 0):

They're part of `mesa`, as libGL*.so.* and the like, usually in /usr/lib*.

Comment: in usr/lib i didnt find the file ,can i know what names it may have

Comment: If you don't have it then perhaps you should consider installing it from its package. Try something starting with `mesa` and ending with `-dev`.

Comment: do u mean manually or please can you tell me the procedure apt get i did the following
libgl1-mesa
libgl1-mesa-dev
libglu1-mesa

glutg3
glutg3-dev
libglui-dev
libglut3
libglut3-dev

can you suggest me more

Comment: Hai Lgnacio,
I did the installation of opengl but where are my lib files stored that info i need ,What names the lib file will have ...etc ..etc

Answer (score 0):

you can check the cmake cache file from any project that has successfully built with opengl, look for **OPENGL_opengl_LIBRARY**

in my case it is:

OPENGL_opengl_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so