# Link error when trying to build a simple OpenGL program

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, netbeans, linker

This is the OpenGL code:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
void display()
{
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
   glutInit(&argc,argv);
   glutCreateWindow("Hello,world!");
   glutDisplayFunc(display);
   glutMainLoop();
}
```

The error messages are:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/zh/workspace/OpenGL/CppApplication_1'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cppapplication_1
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/zh/workspace/OpenGL/CppApplication_1'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
g++ -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lGLEW    -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cppapplication_1 build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEWmx.so
/usr/bin/ld: build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: undefined reference to symbol 'glClear'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cppapplication_1] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/zh/workspace/OpenGL/CppApplication_1'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/zh/workspace/OpenGL/CppApplication_1'
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 124ms)
```

At first I had thought this is because the OpenGL version installed is too low, but `glClear` is available from OpenGL 1.0 and exists in all versions ([see here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GlClear)). This is version information of the OpenGL on my system.
[image]

I built the freeglut 2.8.1 and glew 1.10.0 and have them installed in my system:
[image]

I included the path to the library and specified needed library in the environment:
[image]
[image]

Also, I have read related threads in repository: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204818/simple-opengl-program-fails-to-link-in-ubuntu), [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851557/why-wont-this-glut-program-compile-am-i-missing-libraries-or-headers), but they don't help.

I'm worn out and really can not find what I am missing to build such a simple OpenGL code. Could you please tell me how to troubleshoot this problem? Thank you.

The environment I am using are:
Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit)+
NetBeans 8.0

A hint: when I commented the glClear out, the program can be built successfully.

Edit: For those who working on windows 7 and encountering similar linking problem (OpenGL function not found), Vishwanath gowda's answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171317/how-do-you-install-glut-and-opengl-in-visual-studio-2012) thread may help.

Edit2: We know that Windows supports OpenGL poorly, if you are at the same time using Intel's entrance-level integrated graphics card for which intel's driver provides no additional support of OpenGL, you'll have to make a new Mesa's OpenGL libray according to the guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871781/building-mesa-for-windows-7-mesa-9-1). This can be done because OpenGL is independent of hardware so can be implemented solely by software (A [book](http://www.opengl-redbook.com/) claims so). Be careful to use machine=x86_64 if you are working on 64bit Win7. You can check that by observing the output of dumpbin /headers youropengldll.dll|more. You can also check that the functionality of OpenGL on your windows system is enhanced after that using a software "OpenGL Extension Viewer".

Comment: Why the `-rpath` and the explicit references to files like `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so`?  The `-lglut -lGLU -lGL -lGLEW` should be all you need for linking against OpenGL libraries.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need to compile freeglut and GLEW yourself; Ubuntu has them packaged (as freeglut3-dev and libglew-dev, respectively).

Comment: @Wyzard The purpose of explicit reference to these library files is to tell linker where to find them. If I remove them, more errors come out such as "undefined reference to `glutInit'" which originally does not appear. In addition, I have installed freeglut3-dev and libglew-dev in Ubuntu Software Center. There is a green tick above the icon.

Comment: You shouldn't have to tell the linker where to find them.  The `-lGL` tells the linker to look for a `libGL.so` in the system's default library directories, which includes `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` on a 64-bit Ubuntu system.  There's no need for explicit paths to tell the system linker where to find a system library.

Comment: @Wyzard I have removed them and more errors come out such as "undefined reference to `glutInit'", which originally does not appear if I told linker where to locate them by explicitly specifying library files.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't link both GLEW and GLEWmx; they're different builds of the same library.  Unless you're using multiple GL contexts (an advanced thing to do), just use the regular GLEW library.

Answer (score 13):

I'm able to compile your example program on a 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 system using this command:

```
g++ example.c -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -lglut -o example
```

The order of the link options is important:  libraries have to be specified *after* the object files that depend on them.  From the [GCC documentation for the `-l` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options):

> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus, `‘foo.o -lz bar.o’` searches library `‘z’` after file `foo.o` but before `bar.o`. If `bar.o` refers to functions in `‘z’`, those functions may not be loaded.

(Strangely, the program compiles without errors on my Debian systems even if I put the `-l` options *first*.  But not on Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 3):

OK, I've found the key: I should explicitly specify one more library file that contains needed OpenGL function: libGL.so, as the following image shows:

[image]

Adding a few more lines, this is the output of this simple OpenGL program:

[image]

I think this should be a NetBeans-specific problem, maybe not appear on other IDE like eclipse.

edit: Although the above approach works, the key is to set the link option in NetBeans. All we need to do is type "-lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -lglut" in the Project Properties -> Linker -> Additional Options, as the image below shows:

[image]

Thank Wyzard for pointing out this.

Comment: You shouldn't be specifying those explicit `.so` files at all; you just need to configure NetBeans to put the `-l` options in the right place.  See my answer.

Comment: @Wyzard Yes, you are right. I have editted my answer to reflect your idea.