# Installing OpenGL on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: c++, opengl, ubuntu, makefile

I am a university student trying to setup my home desktop with Ubuntu 13.10 for OpenGL development. I have installed all of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859501/learning-opengl-in-ubuntu/1988688#1988688) libraries. Our first assignment was to write a simple program and a generic makefile that would work for the rest of the semester. This worked perfectly in the Computer Labs on campus.

My main.c file:

```
# include <GL/glut.h>

void display();

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
  glutInit(&argc , argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH );
  glutInitWindowSize(640 , 480) ;
  glutCreateWindow("Practical 1");
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
}

void display()
{
  glClearColor(0.0 , 0.0 , 1.0 , 1.0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glFlush();
  glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

And my makefile:

```
STUDENT_NUMBER = 1234567890
TASK = practical
NUMBER =1

OBJECTS=$(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(shell ls *.C)))
WARNING_FLAGS = -Wall  -Wextra -Weffc++ -Winit -self -Wmissing -include -dirs -Wswitch -default -Wswitch -enum -Wunused -parameter -Wstrict -overflow=5 -Wfloat -equal -Wshadow -Wc++0x -compat -Wconversion -Wsign -conversion-Wmissing -declarations -Wstrict -null -sentinel -Woverloaded -virtual -Wsign -promo -Werror -pedantic -Wcast -qual
FORMATTING_FLAGS = -fno  -pretty -templates -fmessage -length=80 -fdiagnostics -show -option
CFLAGS = ${WARNING_FLAGS} ${FORMATTING_FLAGS} g -std=c++0x -pipe -frepo
LDLIBS = -lGL -lglut -lGLEW -lGLU -lX11 -lXi -lm -lrt -lpng
LDFLAGS =
CC = g++
TARGET = main

all: ${OBJECTS}
    ${CC} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS} $^ -o ${TARGET}

%.o: %.c
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c ${LDFLAGS} $< -o $@

makefile.dep: *.[Ch]
    for i in *.C; do gcc -MM "$${i}"; done > $@
include makefile.dep

clean:
    rm ${OBJECTS} *.rpo *.gch makefile.dep ${TARGET}

tar:
    make clean; tar -cvjf ${STUDENT_NUMBER}_${TASK}_${NUMBER}.tar.bz2 *
```

When trying to compile on my home desktop I get these erors:

```
g++  -lGL -lglut -lGLEW -lGLU -lX11 -lXi -lm -lrt -lpng main.o -o main
main.o: In function `main':
main.C:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `glutInit'
main.C:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'
main.C:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowSize'
main.C:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `glutCreateWindow'
main.C:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to `glutDisplayFunc'
main.C:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `glutMainLoop'
main.o: In function `display()':
main.C:(.text+0x76): undefined reference to `glClearColor'
main.C:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `glClear'
main.C:(.text+0x85): undefined reference to `glFlush'
main.C:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `glutSwapBuffers'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I think I might be missing some library or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc), you need to specify the dependant libraries in after the objects that reference them in your linker command:

```
g++ main.o -lGL -lglut -lGLEW -lGLU -lX11 -lXi -lm -lrt -lpng -o main
```

I'm not an expert on makefile syntax, but I think changing the 'all' section of your makefile like this might work:

```
all: ${OBJECTS}
    ${CC} ${LDFLAGS} $^ ${LDLIBS} -o ${TARGET}
```

Comment: It worked thank you. I did not think that this would have been the problem since this exact makefile worked in the computer labs.

Comment: Glad to know it worked! The difference in behavior could be due to different compiler versions or environment variables...